# "TO" parameter << feed dialog on Facebook

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I have a little trouble. I'm using the script, which is below. The problem is here, that i need to make that when i click on "post" button, there must popup the list of my friends and i have to choose one. I cant solve this, tried by chaning "to" parameter to blank and many other ways.

Thank you. Here is the code:

```
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "asdasdasdasd", status: true, frictionlessRequests : true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          to: '100001987316260',

          link: 'asdasdasdasdl',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Nazwa',
          caption: 'Podnazwa',
          description: 'gówno gówno gówno gówno gówno gówno gówno.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to have friend selector in `feed` dialog

The closest behavior you can get here is by using `stream.share` or `send` dialog instead

**[stream.share](http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/stream.share)** is used for sharing a URL (the data is read from the `og` metadata on the url) - the information on the "post" can't be set by you - but the user have the option to select a friend and post on his timeline

```
<script>
var share = {
  method: 'stream.share',
  u: 'http://LINK.TO/SHARE/'
};

FB.ui(share, callback_function);
</script>
```

**send** is used to send a link to friend/group/email as a private message. an example for use:

```
<script>
var publish = {
  method: 'send',
  link: 'http://LINK.TO/SHARE'
};

FB.ui(publish, callback_function);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. BUT, is there a way to put own link in stream share? I will explain it in this way. On my site, user generates a link that he have to send onto chosen friend from his friend list.

Comment: of course - just put it in the `u` property (replace the `http://LINK.TO/SHARE/` in my example)

Comment: one more question. There isnt the option to exclude posting on own timeline (in stream.share)? I mean, to make posting possible only by typing a friend?

Comment: no. the only thing you can do is developing a custom friend selector (which will require you to ask the user for basic permissions) and then use the `feed` dialog with the `to` parameter based on his selection